# How to add radio button to my website in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, radio-button

I am using WordPress for my website.
I want to add radio buttons to my WordPress page when a radio button is selected I want to display a table below. Can anybody help me

Comment: you create a custom page and add radio button to this. And use jQuery to show or hide data table

Answer (score 0):

> Hello maybe more details help ppl to tell you better answer. but with
>   this much of information i'v got something for you : this is just
>   sample. you just need to edit for your specific purpose.
>   ** put html code in **wordpress editor** ( put in editor section, not visual, visual editor maybe auto convert some tags)
>
> ** put js codes into your js script tag some where!! if you don't have any idea just use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/)
>
> ** if **jQuery** not worked add this lines to function.php of your theme or child-theme to add jQuery library to your page(99% wordpress load it by **default**) :

```
// include custom jQuery
function shapeSpace_include_custom_jquery() {

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shapeSpace_include_custom_jquery');
```

> HTML CODE :

```
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="orange" id="orange">
    <label for="orange">orange</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="apple" id="apple">
    <label for="apple">apple</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="banana" id="banana">
    <label for="banana">banana</label>
  </div>
  <div id="show-table"></div>
</form>
```

> SCRIPT CODE:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("input").on("click", function () {
            var checkedNode = $("input:checked").val();
            var orangTable = '<table style="width:100%"><tr><th>fruit</th></tr><tr><td>name</td></tr><tr><td>orang</td></tr></table>';
            var appleTable = '<table style="width:100%"><tr><th>fruit</th></tr><tr><td>name</td></tr><tr><td>apple</td></tr></table>';
            var bananaTable = '<table style="width:100%"><tr><th>fruit</th></tr><tr><td>name</td></tr><tr><td>banana</td></tr></table>';

            switch (checkedNode) {
                case 'orange':
                    $("#show-table").html(orangTable);
                    break;
                case 'apple':
                    $("#show-table").html(appleTable);
                    break;
                case 'banana':
                    $("#show-table").html(bananaTable);
                    break;

                default:

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

> specific table assigned to each button will display inside div
>   with **id="show-table"** when that button **selected**. you can outspread this
>   method for what purpose you have. just know this is not efficient
>   method or best way. ***it's just a way ..***